# Почему не получается подключиться к БД и записать туда данные из формы?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, sqlite3, qt-designer

Я пишу программу (с помощью *PyQt5*), в которой есть регистрация на отдельной форме. 
Оттуда я хочу брать данные и помещать их в БД *sqlite*, чтобы люди могли войти в свой "аккаунт" после регистрации.

Но почему-то весь код падает с ошибкой именно после попытки занести данные в БД.

Проверяла тип данных - все сходится, по оформлению запроса вроде все нормально. Есть БД **`base_persons.db`** с таблицей "**`persons`**", где 7 столбцов: id, person, data, rost, ves, login, password. 
Id формируется сам, поэтому я его не упоминаю при запросе.

Вот код, надеюсь на помощь.
Класс формы, сформированный Qt Designer:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
   def setupUi(self, Form):
       Form.setObjectName("Form")
       Form.resize(382, 367)
       self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
       self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 341, 331))
       self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
       self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
       self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
       self.label_error = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.label_error.setObjectName("label_error")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_error, 13, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_name.setInputMask("")
       self.line_name.setMaxLength(32767)
       self.line_name.setObjectName("line_name")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_name, 3, 0, 1, 1)
       self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 4, 0, 1, 1)
       self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 6, 0, 1, 1)
       self.btn_prodolg = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.btn_prodolg.setObjectName("btn_prodolg")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_prodolg, 12, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_password.setInputMask("")
       self.line_password.setObjectName("line_password")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_password, 11, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_login = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_login.setInputMask("")
       self.line_login.setMaxLength(32767)
       self.line_login.setObjectName("line_login")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_login, 10, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_rost = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_rost.setPrefix("")
       self.line_rost.setMaximum(300)
       self.line_rost.setObjectName("line_rost")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_rost, 7, 0, 1, 1)
       self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.label.setObjectName("label")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_ves = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_ves.setPrefix("")
       self.line_ves.setMaximum(300)
       self.line_ves.setObjectName("line_ves")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_ves, 9, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_data = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_data.setObjectName("line_data")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_data, 5, 0, 1, 1)
       self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_4, 8, 0, 1, 1)
       self.retranslateUi(Form)
       QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

   def retranslateUi(self, Form):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
       self.label_error.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">Введите все данные!</span></p></body></html>"))
       self.line_name.setPlaceholderText("Ваше имя")
       self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">Ваша дата рождения:</span></p></body></html>"))
       self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">Ваш рост:</span></p></body></html>"))
       self.btn_prodolg.setText(_translate("Form", "Продолжить"))
       self.line_password.setPlaceholderText("Пароль")
       self.line_login.setPlaceholderText("Логин")
       self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Введите свои данные, </span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">а после нажмите кнопку &quot;Продолжить&quot;.</span></p></body></html>"))
       self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">Ваш вес:</span></p></body></html>"))
```

Класс, сделанный мною:

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class RegForm(QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_prodolg.clicked.connect(self.prodolg)

    def prodolg(self):
        lineEdits = self.findChildren(QLineEdit)
        print(f'{lineEdits}')  #
        text = ''
        for lineEdit in lineEdits:
            if not lineEdit.text():
                if lineEdit is self.line_name:
                    text += 'Заполните поле имени' + '\n'
                elif lineEdit is self.line_login:
                    text += 'Заполните поле пароля' + '\n'
                else:
                    text += 'Заполните поле логина' + '\n'
        if text:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание!', text)
        else:
            self.hide()
        self.login = self.line_login.text()
        self.rost = self.line_rost.text()
        self.ves = self.line_ves.text()
        self.password = self.line_password.text()
        self.data = self.line_data.text()
        self.person = self.line_name.text()

        self.rost = int(self.rost)
        self.ves = int(self.ves)
        print(type(self.rost), type(self.data), type(self.login), type(self.person), type(self.password),
              type(self.ves))
        con = sqlite3.connect('base_persons.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO persons(person, data, rost, ves, login, password
                     VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (self.person, self.data, self.rost,
                     self.ves, self.login, self.password)).fetchall() 

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
reg_form_create = RegForm()
reg_form_create.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все началось с того что вы где-то потеряли скобку и немного еще.

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_Form(object):
   def setupUi(self, Form):
       Form.setObjectName("Form")
       Form.resize(382, 367)
       self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
       self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 341, 331))
       self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
       self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
       self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
       self.label_error = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.label_error.setObjectName("label_error")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_error, 13, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_name.setInputMask("")
       self.line_name.setMaxLength(32767)
       self.line_name.setObjectName("line_name")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_name, 3, 0, 1, 1)
       self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 4, 0, 1, 1)
       self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 6, 0, 1, 1)
       self.btn_prodolg = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.btn_prodolg.setObjectName("btn_prodolg")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btn_prodolg, 12, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_password = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_password.setInputMask("")
       self.line_password.setObjectName("line_password")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_password, 11, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_login = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_login.setInputMask("")
       self.line_login.setMaxLength(32767)
       self.line_login.setObjectName("line_login")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_login, 10, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_rost = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_rost.setPrefix("")
       self.line_rost.setMaximum(300)
       self.line_rost.setObjectName("line_rost")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_rost, 7, 0, 1, 1)
       self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.label.setObjectName("label")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_ves = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_ves.setPrefix("")
       self.line_ves.setMaximum(300)
       self.line_ves.setObjectName("line_ves")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_ves, 9, 0, 1, 1)
       self.line_data = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.line_data.setObjectName("line_data")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_data, 5, 0, 1, 1)
       self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
       self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
       self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_4, 8, 0, 1, 1)
       self.retranslateUi(Form)
       QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

   def retranslateUi(self, Form):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
       self.label_error.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">Введите все данные!</span></p></body></html>"))
       self.line_name.setPlaceholderText("Ваше имя")
       self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">Ваша дата рождения:</span></p></body></html>"))
       self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">Ваш рост:</span></p></body></html>"))
       self.btn_prodolg.setText(_translate("Form", "Продолжить"))
       self.line_password.setPlaceholderText("Пароль")
       self.line_login.setPlaceholderText("Логин")
       self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">Введите свои данные, </span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:12pt;\">а после нажмите кнопку &quot;Продолжить&quot;.</span></p></body></html>"))
       self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-size:10pt;\">Ваш вес:</span></p></body></html>")) 
       

class RegForm(QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.btn_prodolg.clicked.connect(self.prodolg)

    def prodolg(self):
        lineEdits = self.findChildren(QLineEdit)
#        print(* lineEdits, sep='\n')  

        for lineEdit in lineEdits:
            if not lineEdit.text():
                msg = QMessageBox.information(
                    self, 'Внимание!', 
                    'Что-то пошло не так. \nВсе поля должны быть ЗАПОЛНЕНЫ.')
                return
# ???        else:
# ???            self.hide()
            
        self.login = self.line_login.text()
        self.rost = self.line_rost.text()
        self.ves = self.line_ves.text()
        self.password = self.line_password.text()
        self.data = self.line_data.text()
        self.person = self.line_name.text()

        self.rost = int(self.rost)
        self.ves = int(self.ves)
        
        print(type(self.person), '\n',  type(self.data), '\n',
              type(self.rost),  '\n', type(self.ves), '\n',
              type(self.login), '\n', type(self.password))
              
        con = sqlite3.connect('base_persons.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        
# +++ vvv
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------> v <--
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO persons(person, data, rost, ves, login, password)
                     VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (self.person, self.data, self.rost,
                     self.ves, self.login, self.password))
                     
        con.commit()  
        sql = f"SELECT * FROM persons"        
        cur.execute(sql)
        
        rez = cur.fetchall()
        print(* rez, sep='\n')  
        
        self.line_login.clear()
        self.line_name.clear()
        self.line_password.clear()
        self.line_rost.clear()
        self.line_ves.clear()
# +++ ^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = RegForm()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @suyuse что не так?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все работает <3

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, что обозначают "+++vvv" и подобные строки?

Comment: @suyuse пожалуйста. Так  "+++vvv" ...  "+++^^^"  я посто выделяю блок, в котором я вносил изменения.